# Displaying Greek Characters in a Label (Visual Studio C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an application that uses google translate to translate words.
I need to display Greek words in a label .... is it this possible to show greek characters?

Comment: Yes, no problem.  What is the *real* issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can represent a Unicode character in C# as `char c = '\u03BB'`, where 03BB is the code point you want in hex.

Comment: Or as char c = 'λ'. Which would be a lot easier (even if copy-and-paste because you didn't have an appropriate keyboard) if there were more than one or two such chars.